# How to reindex a data frame by a custom dict?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good morning!

In my script I have a DataFrame that could have between 1 and 3 rows and always 2 columns. Here I show two different examples of my possible df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_col': ['L', 'V'], 'counter': [30, 4]})
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name_col': ['VE'], 'counter': [10]})
```

My objective is to get always a df like the following (in brackets for the second example above):

```
df = 
   name_col   counter
0        VE    0 (10)          
1         V     4 (0)
2         L    30 (0)
```

I mean, I want to have always this 3 values, `VE, V, L`, in that order, in my final df. I've already tried different combinations of reindex and map, but nothing works a bit...

Thanks you very much in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an answer could be:

```
new_df   = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'name_col': ['VE', 'V', 'L']})
df_final = new_df.merge(df, on = 'name_col', how = 'outer').fillna(0)
```

Do you think this is a good approach?

Comment: I'd probably go for: `df.set_index('name_col').reindex(['VE', 'V', 'L']).fillna(0).reset_index()`

Comment: Yeah, I think your answer is better than mine!